# how to find the obtain key-value pairs from a generic map class

Tags: java, generics

Here I have created a **parameterized** type of Map in a single Generic class. The problem which I am facing is that once I have added 5 key pair value on this Map object. I am kind of confused how to obtain back those 5 pairs back with using map object reference value. As you can see that I am able to obtain Key value using loop 1. This is obtained while key-value pairs are added to the map object.

Now once I have added all key-value pairs to map object 'mp', I want to know how can I obtain all key pair values back?

Take a look at code that would make it more clear.

```
class Maps<K, V> {
K key;
V value;
int size;

Maps(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public void add(K k, V v) {
    key = k;
    value = v;

}

public void show() {
    System.out.print("key=" + key);
    System.out.println("  value=" + value);
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}}

class MyMaps {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Maps<Integer, String> mp = new Maps<Integer, String>(5);
    System.out.println("mp=" + mp);

    // Loop1
    for (int i = 0; i < mp.getSize(); i++) {
        mp.add(i + 1, "JAI " + i);
        mp.show();
    }

    // Loop2

    for (int i = 0; i < mp.getSize(); i++) {

        System.out.println(mp);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code makes absolutely no sense. It's too early for you to use generics. You first need to go back to basics and learn what an object is, what instance and static variables are, what `this` is, how to create objects. You have a single Maps object here, modified 5 times and added 5 times to an array. You also need to learn to indent your code (the IDE cando that for you), and to respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Is `Map.entrySet()`, `Map.keySet()` or `Map.values()` what you are looking for?

Comment: These are in present in java.util.* package. I have designed my own Map here. Keeping it simple if you can guide me a way to obtain back input key pair value back. One obvious solution is to implement above functions as you suggested in the above Maps class.

Comment: Adding to what Nizet has already said. I don't think you have thought through the requirements also. Your implementation strategy will depend on what you want your map to do. Questions on insertion order, sorting order, concurrent modification etc will govern your approach. Also think about other features of map like key uniqueness etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to access is the map entries (aka key, value pairs):

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mp.entrySet()) {
   Integer key = entry.getKey();
   String value = entry.getValue();
   // do whatever you need to do with key and value
}
```